# how to put a limit for mailcatchers inbox?

Tags: mailcatcher

I am looking for a way to limit the "inbox" for the mailcatcher. Is it possible to set an inbox limit for last 7 days for example?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it by editing the docker-compose.yaml file

services:
mailcatcher:
image: sj26/mailcatcher:v0.8.2
command: mailcatcher --foreground --ip=0.0.0.0  --messages-limit=300